# My Visual Studio 2010 IDE keeps opening when closed, why?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crash

I'm having problems with the IDE since it keeps opening when I tried to closed it. Do you have the same problem and solution for that?

**Edit**
I recently install hotfixes:

- [crashes on shutdown] VS10-KB2275326-x86
- [insufficient memory bug when copy-paste] VS10-KB2251084-x86
- [search box increased size bug] VS10-KB2268081-x86
- [unnescessarily scrolling in context menus] VS10-KB2345133-x86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this hotfix [KB2275326 – The Visual Studio 2010 development environment crashes on shutdown](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB2275326)

Comment: Unfortunately this link is now broken.

Comment: The KB fix is included in VS2010 SP1.

Answer (score 0):

There's a checkbox in visual studio 2010 that asks if it should restart automatically when it crashes. So if its crashing then this is the expected behavior but if its opening after you click the exit button i have no idea about its cause.

Comment: Would you show me which option particularly? Looking for it by nake eyes get me bored!

Comment: I don't know how you can find it but this seems to be a future feature https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/569754/add-ability-to-disable-auto-restart-on-crash?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: you get the checkbox when visual studio crashes it will ask you if you want to restart

Comment: I see what you mean but for some reason the dialog you mentioned, i.e. the one with the checkbox, doesn't appear. I want to vote you up back but SE says that it need to be updated befor it can be voted up.